# how to remove YouTube search bar from web-view of a channel?

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I am making web view app of a YouTube channel, but don't know how to remove YouTube search bar in web view . 
I am doing this in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use YouTube API through which you can efficiently load YouTube data.

WebView only loads the URL and you can't control the content inside of it.
As the docs mention

> With the YouTube Data API, you can add a variety of YouTube features
>   to your application. Use the API to upload videos, manage playlists
>   and subscriptions, update channel settings, and more.

Also there are many samples available through which you can fetch the channels, videos, playlists etc.